# How to search a file for a multi-line pattern and print the matching capture group?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to grep for the value of `BUNDLER VERSION` in Bundler's lock file format. Here is the tail of an example `Gemfile.lock`:

```
  thin
  turbolinks (>= 2.5.2)
  typogruby
  unicorn
  xray-rails (>= 0.1.15)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.4
```

Given the above file, I want a simple bash one-liner that outputs `1.10.4`. In other words, something like:

```
cat Gemfile.lock | [magic here] # => 1.10.4
```

I'm hoping for a solution that works on Mac OS X and common Linux distributions without needing to install any special tools.

So far I've figured out I need a regex like this:

```
/^BUNDLED WITH\n   (\S+)$/
```

How do I "grep" a file for this pattern and print just the capture group?

I looked into `sed` and quickly got frustrated. It seems that sed can't easily handle a pattern that spans multiple lines.

**Bonus:**

Older versions of the lock file format do not have `BUNDLER VERSION`. Ideally the script would output a special value if the pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^BUNDLED WITH/{n;s/\s*//p}' file
```

On finding the required string, get the next line and remove the empty space at the front of the line and print.

Comment: Very nice! Unfortunately doesn't work with `sed` that ships with OS X. :(

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires Ruby, but gets the job done:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read[/^BUNDLED WITH\n   (\S+)$/, 1] || "NOT FOUND"' Gemfile.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way than potong with the bonus:

```
sed -n '/^BUNDLED WITH/{n;s/[ \t]*//g;h;};${g;/./!{s/.*/not found/;};p;};' file
```

details:

The `n` option switches on the silent mode. In this mode, the lines are no more automatically displayed, however you can explicitly display a line with the `p` command.

```
/^BUNDLED WITH/ {  # condition: if a line starts with "BUNDLED WITH" then:
    n;             # overwrite the pattern space with the next line
    s/[ \t]*//g;   # replace all white-spaces with nothing (remove them)
    h;             # store the pattern space content in the buffer
};

$ {                # condition: When the last line is reached then:
    g;             # replace the pattern space with the buffer content
    /./! {               # condition: if the pattern space is "empty" then:
        s/.*/not found/; # replace the pattern space with "not found"
    };
    p; # print the pattern space
};
```

Note: instead of testing if the stored part was not empty with `/./!`, you can be more explicit and use a pattern that describes a version number like: `/[0-9][0-9]*\(\.[0-9][0-9]*\)*/!` or the same with anchors.